# How to convert joomla 1.0 running site into joomla 1.5 site?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I want to convert a running joomla 1.0 based website into joomla 1.5 based site.

For design i will choose any good 1.5 template but How i can import 1.0 databse into 1.5 site's databse. my new joomla 1.5 site will have different url than old 1.0 joomla site.

I want to convert whole things of old 1.0 site to 1.5 site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is, how many extension, components, plugins are you using and is your joomla install clean or hacked? The Joomla Documentations have step by step guidelines on how to migrate from 1.0 to 1.5 and there even is a migration manager/helper.

If you have a non-hacked version, you should follow these instructions:

[Joomla Migration](http://docs.joomla.org/Migrating_from_1.0.x_to_1.5_Stable)

If you have a hacked version and an upgrade doesn't work (try it), then you will have to write your own migration scripts.

Comment: I will use allnew 1.5 native components. I 've installed 1.5 joomla on new place now how to import old databse into new

Comment: I've got a heavily hacked version... chances of upgrading are relatively slim, I fear...